# What CSS selector finds elements based on attribute values, regardless of attribute names?

Tags: html, css

For example, in the elements below, what selector would find everything with a value of "value2", regardless of the attribute's name?

```
<div data-name1="value1"></div>
<div data-name2="value2"></div>
<div data-name3="value2"></div>
<div data-name4="value1"></div>
```

Comment: There is no such CSS selector.  The attribute value selector needs a specific attribute to look for.  You might be able to use JS/jQuery to scan all dom elements and their attributes and if the element has any attribute with a value of "value2", then adds a certain class to it, which you can then style like you want.  But that method will probably be very inefficient - I recommend you try to change your markup instead.

Comment: Have you tried using js to find all everything with "value2" and then adding a specific class to each element that can be styled using css?

Comment: Based on these 2 comments above, it will probably be easier in my case to change the way I generate the markup. It got me wondering if CSS could do this, though.

Comment: as far as i know only jquery or some form of javascript could achieve what you want

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest having a specific attribute and then searching that specific attribute value?

HTML

```
<div data-name="value1"></div>
<div data-name="value2"></div>
<div data-name="value2"></div>
<div data-name="value1"></div>
```

CSS

```
[data-name^='value2'] {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: I'm wanting to target something with a specific value, regardless of the attribute name.

Comment: hmm you might have to look into more than html and css then.