# What SASS or LESS selector finds elements based on attribute values, regardless of attribute names?

Tags: html, css, sass, less

For example, in the elements below, what selector would find everything with a value of "value2", regardless of the attribute's name?

```
<div data-name1="value1"></div>
<div data-name2="value2"></div>
<div data-name3="value2"></div>
<div data-name4="value1"></div>
```

There is [a version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33308961/1122373) (asked be me) limited to pure CSS. This seems like a different enough question to post separately instead of just extending the original.

As a reminder, this question is *not* asking if jQuery can do it.

Comment: If CSS can't do it SASS/LESS can't *write* CSS that can do it. I'm tempted to close this a duplicate but I'll hold off for now.

Comment: I don't know any in LESS. I think your task is wrong. There is an architecture issue. You need to change the approach. Secondly, you should not attach you styles to data-attributes. You need to separate data and view.

Comment: @Paulie_D You are not right. LESS provides some calculating and string manipulation features that overcomes CSS abilities.

Comment: But it still complies to CSS and if CSS can't do it...there you are.

Comment: The question is not about the approach; this is an example. Also, it would be more accurate to say, 'if CSS can't do it *simply*, SASS/LESS can still write CSS that can do it.'

Comment: If CSS can't do **it all** SASS/LESS can't do it either.

Comment: @Paulie_D I have no problem closing it as a duplicate.  Sometimes CSS Preprocessor "problems" are actually CSS problems, even if the OP doesn't realize it when they ask their question.

Comment: Fair enough...I held off just in case there was something I wasn't aware of....but I had a feeling. :)

Comment: If this is truly a duplicate question, kindly provide an answer to the one this is a duplicate of. As of right now, it has no actual answer besides what's written in the comments.

Comment: @adamrowe: The only answer that can be provided to either question (this or the primary) is a resounding **NO**. There is no way in CSS currently, there is no way in CSS in future and I can't see any reason why W3C would add such a selector. It seems an architectural flaw to me.